# Can't find database path after exporting

Tags: vb.net

I have vb.net application which is using Vistadb with following connection string. I am able to export data to excel also. But after exporting to report different than to application directory, program crashes and says that database not found in exported directory. i believe that there is something wrong in connection string but I van't find. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
Dim con As VistaDBConnection
        Dim Cmd As New VistaDBCommand
        Dim constring As String
        constring = String.Format("Data Source =v_slot_database.vdb3", (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)))
        con = New VistaDBConnection(constring)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it. Correct string is like that.

```
constring = String.Format("Data Source =" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\v_slot_database.vdb3")
```